# Uncaught Error: Script error for: tinymce in Magento 2 Admin backend

Tags: magento2, error, admin-panel, script, tinymce

I am facing this error in the admin panel. Due to this error my admin panel menus such as order, customers are not loading. It loading forever. Kindly help me to solve this issue.

```
Uncaught Error: Script error for: tinymce
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
at makeError (require.js:166)
at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)
```

Comment: are you  creating any tabs in the admin   custom form

Comment: No, it not loading for even default menus like customer, orders like that. It sometimes loads but sometimes not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a code in your edit.php file

> app/code/{vendor}/{Module}/Block/Adminhtml/{your folder}/Edit.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Your Folder;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container;

class Edit extends Container
{
 ......
.....
.....
 protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->_formScripts[] = "
            function toggleEditor() {
                if (tinyMCE.getInstanceById('post_content') == null) {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'post_content');
                } else {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'post_content');
                }
            };
        ";

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not using the custom module for that. .